# Obtaining a SINGLE cursor with full name details and phone numbers

Tags: android, contactscontract

I want to create a single Cursor that contains both given name, family name and phone nr. These columns are not located together in any of the containers available under ContactsContract and the only way I've been able to get this information is by first getting a cursor for the names and then getting phone numbers by creating a separate cursor for every contact. This solution forces me to read the data to a local data structure instead of just using an adapter on the cursor and imposes a lot of performance overhead (around ~5s with ~140 contacts with phone numbers).

Is there any way to create two cursors and then join the tables? Or is there any other way?
I have been struggling with this question for the last two days and read about everything I found on google, but really can't get anything working as I want too. This can't really be impossible, or is it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `DISPLAY_NAME` and `NUMBER` from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone`. Try this:

```
Uri uri = Phone.CONTENT_URI;
String[] projection = new String[]
                {Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone._ID}
Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```